# What is the advantage of using annotation over interface type?

Tags: java, types, annotations, java-8

In this [example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/declaring.html), below annotation type(`@interface`):

```
@interface ClassPreamble {
       String author();
       String date();
       int currentRevision() default 1;
       String lastModified() default "N/A";
       String lastModifiedBy() default "N/A";
       // Note use of array
       String[] reviewers();
    }
```

gets compiled to `interface` type:

```
interface annotationtype.ClassPreamble extends java.lang.annotation.Annotation{
    public abstract java.lang.String author();
    public abstract java.lang.String date();
    public abstract int currentRevision();
    public abstract java.lang.String lastModified();
    public abstract java.lang.String lastModifiedBy();
    public abstract java.lang.String[] reviewers();
}
```

So, the annotation type is getting compiled to `interface` type, before runtime.

In java, What is the advantage of using annotation type(`@interface`) over the `interface` type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interfaces are a technique for object modeling, that allow objects to implement behaviors (but not state) associated with multiple types.

Annotations are a technique for embedding typed metadata in your code; this metadata is intended to be consumed by tools (test frameworks, code generators, etc), but they have no language-level semantics.  You could think of them as structured/typed comments attached to certain program elements, that can be accessed via reflection.

Under the hood, annotations are implemented as interfaces, largely as a matter of convenience, but the similarity is probably more confusing than helpful in understanding what they are for.

Comment: With respect to translation, enum type compiles to 'final class'. But enum type is for a different purpose than class. 'class' is used for object modelling. Is this good analogy?

Comment: Enum types are an example where a pattern was pulled into the language.  If Java didn't have enum classes, you could still get the exact same effect by coding to a pattern -- just with more verbosity.  That enums compile to classes is not an accident of convenience, because the "enum pattern" is one fundamentally expressed by classes.  Annotations seem pretty different to me.

Comment: For your point: "**interfaces that allow objects to implement behaviors**". Can I rephrase as,  "interfaces allow objects to implement peripheral(non-core) behaviors"?  Taken from reference **item-18: Interfaces are ideal for defining mixins**. For example: `compareTo()` behavior of `interface Comparable`.

Comment: @overexchange That would be taking it way too far.  Interfaces are also good for defining core behaviors!  For example, List is an interface.  "X is good for Y" does not imply Y is the only, or even more important, thing X is good for.  So, while Comparable and friends are one good category of things interfaces do well, so are List, JDBC Connection, Stream, and many others.

Answer (score 5):

If you do manually what compiler did automatically, you would not define an annotation. According to [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Annotation.html),

> an interface that manually extends [`java.lang.annotation.Annotation`] does not define an annotation type.

Therefore, `@interface` syntax is required to define an annotation in Java.